# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object - как восстановить доступ?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, modx, apache2

Пытаюсь исправить 500 ошибку на тех страницах сайта, где есть авторизация, которая появилась после того как сайт перестал загружаться, на хостинге виден был недостаток оперативной памяти, память была добавлена, виртуальный сервер перезагружен, после чего сайт "встал" но не полностью, на некоторых страницах осталась 500-я ошибка, в том числе выдает ошибку страница внутренней административной панели ModX. В логе apache есть ошибка:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /var/www/core/components/pdotools/model/pdotools/pdofetch.class.php

Файл /var/log/mysql/error.log абсолютно пустой.
Пыталась очистить /core/cache - сайт "ложится" полностью - ошибка 500 на всех страницах. В phpMyAdmin попасть не могу - при вводе пароля root просто очищается форма авторизации, никаких ошибок не выдает.
Скрипты сто лет никто не трогал и не менял, все работало. 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в проблеме и ее исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а кроме Рута, есть  пользователь с доступом к базе, насколько знаю если у пользователя Рут не задан пароль то в phpMyAdmin не пустит.
такое ощущение что у вас сервер баз данных не запущен. попробуйте в консоли сервера service mysql status ввести, если у вас мускул база.

Comment: cпасибо, вы оказались правы, сервер баз данных был остановлен, я запустила его через service mysql start, но теперь вообще весь сайт "лег" - ни ошибок в консоли, ни в логах... В phpMyAdmin теперь пускает, что еще можно сделать чтобы исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, проблема решилась - в логах mysql нашла ошибку - слишком много места таблица с сессиями занимала, очистила таблицу и все заработало.